# 'static: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied - do I need to Box?

Tags: memory, constructor, rust, traits

I'm about to give a trait as argument to store it through a contructor method called `new`.

**The trait for a struct type is given as argument here:**

*renderer*.rs

```
use super::shapes::Shape;

pub struct Renderer;

impl Renderer{
    pub fn set_shape<T : Shape>(&self, shape: T) -> T::Builder{
        T::Builder::new(shape)
    }
}
```

**then the contructor of the `Builder` specified by the associated type will be called**

*shapebuilder.rs*

```
use super::shapes::Shape;
use super::shapes::Rectangle;

pub trait ShapeBuilder{
    fn new<T:Shape>(shape: T) -> Self;
}

pub struct RectangleBuilder{
    shape: Shape<Builder=RectangleBuilder>
}

impl ShapeBuilder for RectangleBuilder{
    fn new<T:Shape>(shape: T) -> Self{
        RectangleBuilder{
            shape: shape as Rectangle
        }
    }
}
```

**at this point I already want to point out the compiler output**

*compiler_output*

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `shapes::Shape<Builder=shapebuilder::RectangleBuilder> + 'static: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied
  --> shapes.rs:14:6
   |
14 | impl Shape for Rectangle{
   |      ^^^^^
   |
   = note: `shapes::Shape<Builder=shapebuilder::RectangleBuilder> + 'static` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
   = note: required because it appears within the type `shapebuilder::RectangleBuilder`
   = note: required by `shapes::Shape`

error: aborting due to previous error
```

I found similar questions here on SO which told something about Boxing. I tried to Box every parameter type to solve the issue. Boxed it like this `shape: Box<T>`. No success. Do I need to box at all? I understand the issue that the compiler is not able to resolve the size of a trait since the specific/concrete struct types can have different sizes depending on their field/properties. Still I'm not able to find a solution. Hope it's trivial.

---

## **NOT involed modules (my opinion) listed for completeness**

*shapes.rs*

```
use super::shapebuilder::ShapeBuilder;
use super::shapebuilder::RectangleBuilder;

pub trait Shape{
    type Builder: ShapeBuilder;
}

#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
pub struct Rectangle{
    pub height: usize,
    pub width: usize,
}

impl Shape for Rectangle{
    type Builder = RectangleBuilder;
}
```

*lib.rs*

```
pub mod renderer;
mod shapes;
mod shapebuilder;
```

Comment: Is this the *smallest* example you can make it? Try to isolate the specific problem, which will make it clearer for both you and us.

Comment: `renderer.rs` and `shapebuilder.rs` are already as small as possible and the only *important* informations. The stuff beginning at the headline **NOT involed modules...** is - as I mentioned - only for completeness because people asked on another question for a all modules to compile and test it themselves. Please be sure to read all headlines first.

Comment: I don't think you see my point correctly - your current code example are not minimal and contain imports from your other files. To make your question clearer, you should find the part of your code that is causing your problem, and **get rid of the rest completely** to make a more simple example that still has the same problem. As it stands, I would need to copy all of your files and directory structure into a project to even reproduce your problem, which would not be necessary if you isolated the problem more.

Comment: Well yea you're right - I'm taking my time to update the question with a more focused example.

Comment: made the code more simple now - I like it more that way either thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the compiler is not really pointing at the source of the error. The problem is here:

```
pub struct RectangleBuilder {
    shape: Shape<Builder=RectangleBuilder>
    //     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this is an unsized type!
}
```

`Shape` is a trait, and using it as a type yields an unsized type. We could box it to fix this error:

```
pub struct RectangleBuilder {
    shape: Box<Shape<Builder=RectangleBuilder>>
}
```

But then, what do we do about the cast here?

```
impl ShapeBuilder for RectangleBuilder {
    fn new<T: Shape>(shape: T) -> Self {
        RectangleBuilder {
            shape: shape as Rectangle
            //     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't cast a generic type!
        }
    }
}
```

If `RectangleBuilder` will indeed be ready to accept any `Shape` whose `Builder` is `RectangleBuilder`, then let's remove the cast and add the appropriate constraints where necessary.

```
pub mod renderer {
    use super::shapes::Shape;
    use super::shapebuilder::ShapeBuilder;

    pub struct Renderer;

    impl Renderer {
        pub fn set_shape<T: Shape + 'static>(&self, shape: T) -> T::Builder {
            T::Builder::new(shape)
        }
    }
}

mod shapes {
    use super::shapebuilder::ShapeBuilder;
    use super::shapebuilder::RectangleBuilder;

    pub trait Shape {
        type Builder: ShapeBuilder;
    }

    #[derive(Clone, Copy)]
    pub struct Rectangle {
        pub height: usize,
        pub width: usize,
    }

    impl Shape for Rectangle {
        type Builder = RectangleBuilder;
    }
}

mod shapebuilder {
    use super::shapes::Shape;

    pub trait ShapeBuilder: Sized {
        fn new<T: Shape<Builder=Self> + 'static>(shape: T) -> Self;
    }

    pub struct RectangleBuilder {
        shape: Box<Shape<Builder=RectangleBuilder> + 'static>,
    }

    impl ShapeBuilder for RectangleBuilder {
        fn new<T: Shape<Builder=Self> + 'static>(shape: T) -> Self {
            RectangleBuilder {
                shape: Box::new(shape)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `'static` bound puts a limit on the references that can be stored in a particular `Shape` instance. `'static` means that the implementations cannot contain references, unless they have the `'static` lifetime.

However, if you'll need to use `Rectangle`'s fields in `RectangleBuilder`, then `RectangleBuilder` should only accept `Rectangle`s, rather than any shape. We can use associated types again to express this.

```
pub mod renderer {
    use super::shapes::Shape;
    use super::shapebuilder::ShapeBuilder;

    pub struct Renderer;

    impl Renderer {
        pub fn set_shape<T: Shape>(&self, shape: T) -> T::Builder {
            T::Builder::new(shape)
        }
    }
}

mod shapes {
    use super::shapebuilder::ShapeBuilder;
    use super::shapebuilder::RectangleBuilder;

    pub trait Shape {
        type Builder: ShapeBuilder<Shape=Self>;
    }

    #[derive(Clone, Copy)]
    pub struct Rectangle {
        pub height: usize,
        pub width: usize,
    }

    impl Shape for Rectangle {
        type Builder = RectangleBuilder;
    }
}

mod shapebuilder {
    use super::shapes::Shape;
    use super::shapes::Rectangle;

    pub trait ShapeBuilder: Sized {
        type Shape: Shape + ?Sized;

        fn new(shape: Self::Shape) -> Self;
    }

    pub struct RectangleBuilder {
        shape: Rectangle,
    }

    impl ShapeBuilder for RectangleBuilder {
        type Shape = Rectangle;

        fn new(shape: Self::Shape) -> Self {
            RectangleBuilder {
                shape: shape
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In `ShapeBuilder`, we've added a `Shape` associated type that specifies what type of `Shape` each `ShapeBuilder` will operate on. `ShapeBuilder::new` now uses this associated type, instead of a type parameter, to specify the type of its operand. Note that the `+ ?Sized` bound is needed because otherwise there's an implicit `+ Sized` bound, and Rust complains that `Shape` doesn't imply `Sized`. Another way to fix this is to add `: Sized` to `Shape`'s definition.

```
pub trait Shape: Sized {
    type Builder: ShapeBuilder<Shape=Self>;
}
```

Comment: Wow...this is very explicit. Rust really needs to have things declared very explicitely. It's hard for me as a Java developer to think about all this - but I am glad that Rust works this way. Let's me understand how code works way better. Gonna test this soluation and mark this as answered asap. thanks